# link to dylib in xcode 4

Tags: xcode4, linker, dylib, xar

I'm trying to use `libxar` inside my `xcode4` project and get the famous "undefined symbols for architecture" error, no matter what arch I choose for building, e.g.:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"xar_open(char const*, int)", referenced from: 
_main in main.o
```

I did what I always did to include the dylib:

- set "library search path" to the path where libxar.dylib is placed
- set "header path" to the path where xar.h is placed (which contains xar_open)
- added libxar.dylib to build phases - link binary with libraries

Did I miss something?

Comment: Are you linking to a 64-bit version of libxar? You're building a 64-bit version of your app, which requires a 64-bit version of libxar. If you're not using ARC in your app, you could try building a 32-bit version of your app and see if that eliminates the link error.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. i tried both, built app and library as 32 and 64 bit. compiling fine, only linking is the problem.